# Error: Deallocating a 2D array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++

Created a MCVE.

I get an error when I try to deallocate a 2D array in the class ConnectNGame.

Here is the code from Source.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ConnectNGame.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
    {
        int connect = 3;
        ConnectNGame game(connect);
        game.~ConnectNGame();
        return 0;
    }
```

Code from ConnectNGame.h

```
#ifndef CONNECTNGAME_H
#define CONNECTNGAME_H

struct Position
{
    int row, col;
};

class ConnectNGame
{
private:
public:
    int rows;
    int cols;
    char** gameBoard;
    ConnectNGame();
    ConnectNGame(int);
    ~ConnectNGame();
};
#endif
```

And ConnectNGame.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ConnectNGame.h"
using namespace std;

ConnectNGame::ConnectNGame()
{
    rows = 0;
    cols = 0;
}

ConnectNGame::ConnectNGame(int pieces)
{
    rows = pieces + 2;
    cols = pieces + 3;
    gameBoard = new char*[rows];
    for (int count = 0; count < rows; count++)
    {
        gameBoard[count] = new char[cols];
        for (int count2 = 0; count2 < cols; count2++){
            gameBoard[count][count2] = ' ';
        }
    }
}
ConnectNGame::~ConnectNGame()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        delete[] gameBoard[i];
    }
    delete[] gameBoard;
}
```

When the destructor is called, the program crashes. I don't know why this is and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me `gameBoard` is *really* a member variable in a class that does *not* practice [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) semantics. Post a [**MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And ideally, toss it all and just use `std::vector<std::vector<char>> gameBoard(rows, std::vector<char>(cols,' '));`.

Comment: @WhozCraig I edited the OP to create a MCVE example of my error. You might be right about the Rule of Three, since I'm not that familiar with it.

Comment: That code has multiple issues, and confirmed my crystal ball still has some teeth. It not only violates the Rule of Three semantics i linked earlier, it also leaves `gameBoard` *indeterminate* in the default constructor. The loop in the destructor will be skipped (as `rows` is zero), but you'll still be passing an indeterminate pointer to the final `delete[]` unless you value initialized your object (in which case `gameBoard` will be `nullptr` and the `delete[]` a no-op.).

Comment: And this *still* isn't a MCVE. There is no code that actually creates nor uses any of these objects, i.e. no `main()`, nor functions that you pass `ConnectNGame` objects to, through, etc. Read the [linked article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)), and consider what I said earlier about just using a vector of vectors.

Comment: What happens to gameBoard and its pointers between these two chunks of code?   I pasted your code into a text file, put a main() around it, and added int rows=4,cols=5. It ran fine, at least no crashes or complaints. (I used gcc on a linux 64-bit machine.)   So maybe some of the pointers are damaged in between.

Comment: *Stop calling the destructor manually.* Remove this line : `game.~ConnectNGame();`. It is called automatically for you on scope-exit. And I still cannot stress enough. You *need* to read that article to see how the wheels can come off this eventually, even when you're *not* manually invoking a destructor (which you should *never* do unless you're playing in placement-new land, and you're not).

Comment: @WhozCraig     I will definitely read up on the Rule of Three. There is a Main in my example, though, in Source.cpp. I will also fix the problems with the default constructor. I'm pretty sure it was calling the destructor manually that was causing the errors. Stupid mistake.